# How to make hash with given values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have included given code

```
@marks= Mark.all
```

which gives me this

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Mark id: 1, name: "xyz", number: 20>, #<Mark id: 2, name: "abc", number: 25>, #<Mark id: 3, name: "toy", number: 40>, #<Mark id: 4, name: "tim", number: 35>, #<Mark id: 5, name: "vim", number: 45>]>
```

Now I want to make a new hash of marks i.e  {1=>"xyz", 2=>"abc", 3=>"toy", 4=>"tim", 5=>"vim"}. Please guide me how to obtain this thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 @marks  = Mark.all
 @hashed_marks = Hash[@marks.collect{|v| [ v.id, v.name ] }]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @marks  = Mark.all
 @hashed_marks = Hash[@marks.pluck(:id, :name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
@marks = Mark.all
marks_hash = {}

@marks.each do |mark|
  marks_hash.merge( mark.attributes )
end

marks_hash
```

Another way you can do it is:

```
@marks.as_json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your marks code to use pluck

```
@marks = Mark.pluck(:id, :name)
```

You will then just get a multi dimensional array

```
[[1, "xyz"], [2, "abc"]]
```

Then you can just do

```
@hash = Hash[@marks] => {1=>"xyz", 2=>"abc"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_hash = Hash.new
Mark.all.each{|m| my_hash[m.id] = m.name }
```

**Or**

If you are using **Rails 4** then use **[pluck](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)** and [**to_h**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h)

```
my_hash = Mark.pluck(:id, :name).to_h
```